# SQL Query to create a field based on Dates

Tags: postgresql, date, calculated-field

I have a dataset where an id moves through stages A to D sequentially (A to B, B to C & C to D).

I a have timestamps that track when an id entered a particular stage.**Here is what my data looks like**

[image]

So I am interested in creating a **field called 'Status'** that shows the number of B, C, D converted based on the timestamp of A

For instance;

In the month of **Aug'19 The number of 'A's=7**

The number of **'B' converted when the timestamp of A is Aug'19 (irrespective of the date under Date_B)=5**

The number of **'C' converted when the timestamp of A is Aug'19(irrespective of the date under Date_C)=5**

The number of **'D' converted when the timestamp of A is Aug'19(irrespective of the date under Date_D)=5**

**I tried using union all,** but its **gives me the 'Status' in real time meaning** 'date_B' under id 1 gets a date of Sept'19 not Aug'19.This is the query I used;

```
SELECT id,
CAST (Date_A AS DATE) AS 'Pivot Date',
'A' AS 'Status'
FROM table1

UNION ALL

SELECT id,
CAST (Date_B AS DATE) AS 'Pivot Date',
'B' AS 'Status'
FROM table1

UNION ALL

SELECT id,
CAST (Date_C AS DATE) AS 'Pivot Date',
'C' AS 'Status'
FROM table1

UNION ALL

SELECT id,
CAST (Date_D AS DATE) AS 'Pivot Date',
'D' AS 'Status'
FROM table1
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not totally sure if this is what you want, but try this:

```sql
SELECT
    *, -- or only id or whatever
    COUNT(date_a) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('month', date_a)) AS a_of_the_month,
    COUNT(date_b) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('month', date_a)) AS already_converted_to_b,
    COUNT(date_c) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('month', date_a)) AS already_converted_to_c,
    COUNT(date_d) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('month', date_a)) AS already_converted_to_d
FROM table1;
```

Perhaps you only wanted the months and your numbers:

```sql
SELECT
    date_trunc('month', date_a),
    COUNT(date_a) AS a_of_the_month,
    COUNT(date_b) AS already_converted_to_b,
    COUNT(date_c) AS already_converted_to_c,
    COUNT(date_d) AS already_converted_to_d
FROM table1
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', date_a);
```

In both cases you might also replace `COUNT(date_a)` by `COUNT(*)` if `date_a` has to be set always.

Comment: @lslingre thanks a lot! I have one question about the second query, when I use  'SELECT id' in the second query, I get an error 'Column 'id' must be used in a Group By clause ' or used in an 'aggregate function'.I was under the impression that I can select ids and other columns too.

Comment: I understand that a subquery might help, but am not able to understand why it won't work without a subquery.Could you point me towards the appropriate resource?Thanks

Comment: You can only use columns that you used to group (or which are functionally dependend on them), since otherwise there might be multiple different values to choose from. Aggregate functions (as the ```COUNT``` in the second query) take all these different values and calculate one result for them, so they can also be used with grouping. The ```COUNT``` in the first query is instead a window function, which will not lead to grouping. For further information look here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html